# Can I import in intellij only one Bazel package (BUILD)?

Tags: intellij-idea, bazel, monorepo

I have a monorepo and trying to move it to Bazel.
Currently it has multiple acyclically interdependent projects (either libraries, or applications).

It's important for the team to be able to import a subset of the projects so that the IDE is not overwhelmed with thousands of files.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean multiple workspaces?

Comment: What build system/s where you using before hand?

Comment: I mean multiple builds, only one Workspace

Comment: @silvergasp gradle

Comment: I'm not super familiar with IntelliJ or Gradle. So I'm unlikely to be able to put together a complete answer. But I think what @Vertexwahn was alluding to might work for you. By creating multiple separate bazel WORKSPACES per project may work for you. As you would just be opening a single subdirectory/workspace in your IDE. You can use the `local_repository` rule to express interdependence between WORKSPACES.

Comment: You can do monorepo in intellij, but what do you mean by one bazel package. Bazel code base can be imported in intellij IDE and build the code & test cases using bazel plugin.